# Research-style frequency table formatting with R Markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

I am running frequencies for a peer-reviewed research paper and need to combine output into a table. An example of the format can be found [here](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/full/10.1089/trgh.2019.0032) under "Results".

Essentially, it follows a style of heading/variable, with categories indented below, and n(%), either in one column or two.

I've tried to figure out a way to combine `summarytools::freq()` and `knittr::kable()` to get tables styled this way. One thing that I've tried is combining multiple `freq() %>% as.data.frame()` statements with `bind_rows()`. But that output is not very pretty.

I'm trying to avoid having to do a lot of cutting and pasting in Word because there were be a lot of tables, and I would like to get as close as possible to the desired format in my output. Any pointers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The example you refer to uses cross-tabulation (joint frequencies for two categorical variables). So `summarytools::freq()` is probably not what you're looking for here, even though technically it can work if you use it with `stby()`. `summarytools::ctable()` would bring you a step closer, but there are other packages that might be better suited for this purpose, I'm thinking maybe *tableone*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xtable package in Rmarkdown to generate literature/research tables.
This is the rmarkdown setup I used:

````
---
title: "Summary_results_as_research_table_SO"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r , results="asis"}
library(xtable)
xtable(summary(iris))

```
````

Result: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
It seems like xtable is only usable for HTML or PDF documents; I'm trying to output this to Word so that it can be further manipulated. Is that not possible?
I'm also trying to use formatting like indentation under the headings. I don't think xtable specifically handles that.